# How to speed up mysql search

Tags: mysql, search

I am using this code for reading from the db, but the results that I get are kind of slow. So I need some help about that problem.

```sql
SELECT mod_part.id AS mp_id,parts.id as part_id,outlets.name as out_name, parts.part_name as part_name, parts.brand, outlets.sell, outlets.cost, outlets.qty, outlets.comp, parts.supplier, brands.name AS brand_name 
FROM outlets,models,manufacturers,brands,parts,mod_part 
WHERE outlets.part_id=mod_part.id 
      AND mod_part.part_id=parts.id 
      AND brands.id=mod_part.brand_id 
      AND mod_part.model_id=models.id 
      AND parts.man_id=manufacturers.id 
      AND (MATCH (manufacturers.name) AGAINST ('".$_GET['search']."') 
      OR MATCH (parts.part_name) AGAINST('".$_GET['search']."') 
      OR MATCH(models.name) AGAINST('".$_GET['search']."')) 
GROUP BY parts.id
```

Comment: More detail would be  helpful, including table structure, and approximate size. Otherwise any help is a stab in the dark.

Comment: **NO**. Do not put `$_GET` variables directly into your query if you value your career. **Always** use [proper SQL escaping](http://bobby-tables.com/php). Someone could make your search a whole lot faster by **dropping all your tables**.

Comment: Do you have indexes on the fields you are using to link outlets,models,manufacturers,brands,parts,mod_part?  If you don't have indexes or have poorly designed ones, this is going to get really slow once you have a largish number of records in those tables.  Also I'd suggest moving the `id = id` type stuff to JOINS.  If you have proper indexes on those ids, the database engine *may* be able to do something more optimal if you use JOINS instead of the where clause to link these tables.

Comment: hello bobby tables... http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: more detail about table `outlets` . outlets.id is equal to what ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try this with inner join

```
$search = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['search']);  // escape from sql injection here
```

and then use it in your sql (please use PDO or SQLI instead)

```
"SELECT mo.id AS mp_id,p.id as part_id,o.name as out_name,p.part_name as part_name,p.brand,o.sell,o.cost,o.qty,o.comp,p.supplier,b.name AS brand_name 
 FROM outlets 
 INNER JOIN models m  ON  m.id = mo.model_id
 INNER JOIN parts p ON  mo.part_id= p.id 
 INNER JOIN manufacturers ma ON p.man_id=ma.id 
 INNER JOIN brands b ON  bid=mo.brand_id
 INNER JOIN mod_part mo ON mo.part_id=mo.id 

WHERE 
   (MATCH (ma.name)  AGAINST ('".$search."')
   OR MATCH (p.part_name)  AGAINST('".$search."') 
   OR MATCH(m.name)  AGAINST('".$search."'))
GROUP BY p.id ";
```

Answer (score 0):

If the query is slow, try looking at the [explain plan](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/explain.html). Otherwise, you'll have to give more information, such as table structure, indexes, code, etc.

Also, you are allowing SQL injection. Please read up on that subject and fix the code. If you tell which language you are using, I can try to add some links. Otherwise, look into "binding" your variables.